# Offline use of specific font (Router Wifi Agreement)

Tags: html, svg

I have developed at a moment a custom Wifi Agreement page for my router.
I want to use a specific Webfont "Folio W01 Light".

all CSS styles, javascript, needs only to be in this .html, so I am not allowed to outsource something.

I am actually already using inline .svg, is there something similar for fonts?

Thanks

Comment: convert the font to a data url

Comment: You should improve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Convert the font to data URI and paste that to your HTML